# Flutter project exceeds .dex Method Reference Count limit

Tags: android, flutter

Why does a Flutter project ***exceed 64K*** method reference in its `.dex` file?

I am wondering what the cause of this could be:
In a *rather small* Flutter project I use 13 *plugins*. Without [Multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex), the Android build fails because it vastly exceeds the method reference limit.

Is there any trick (e.g. Gradle related) that would allow to shrink the method reference count because I think that such a project should not exceed the limit?
(*if you want further information on why I think that this is odd, please take a look at older revisions of this question*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use ProGuard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) to eliminate unused classes at compile time. This will reduce your method count by a considerable amount.

You will need to adjust the ProGuard rules to work with Flutter like the [Flutter documentation explains here](https://flutter.io/android-release/#step-1---configure-proguard).

Answer (score 36):

I had the same problem and the fix for me was increasing the `minSdkVersion` in the `app/build.bradle` like this

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        minSdkVersion 21 // change this to 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Answer (score 24):

If you are using `minSdkVersion` less than 21, you can do the following to enable multidex.
In your app level build.gradle change as follows:

1. Add `multiDexEnabled true` to `defaultConfig`

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15 
    targetSdkVersion 28
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

2. Add multidex dependency

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

You can refer [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) for more information.

Answer (score 11):

in your `android/app/build` file increase the `minsdkversion` from 16 to 21 under **defautConfig**.
Some have even increased it to 28 but it worked for me at 21.
Here is the link to the [issue on git](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20747)

Edit:  `multiDexEnabled: true` also works for some  under the same **defautConfig**.

Answer (score 5):

in the build.gradle under the defaultConfig  add the multiDexEnabled true

```
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: That solved it for me, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: use the **multidex Library.**
Option 2: increase your **min SDK to 21 or higher**

Detailed explanation on using Multidex Library:
Versions of the platform prior to Android 5.0 (API level 21) use the Dalvik runtime for executing app code. By default, Dalvik limits apps to single classes.dex bytecode file per APK. In order to get around this limitation, you can add the multidex library to the module-level build.gradle file:

1. Steps to fixing it: set multiDex enabled to true

> defaultConfig {

> ```
>     minSdkVersion 15 
>     targetSdkVersion 28
>     ...
>     multiDexEnabled true
> }
> ```

2. Add multidex dependency:

> dependencies {
> implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1" }

Detailed explanation on why increasing your **min SDK** to **21** in your **android/app/build.gradle** works is:
Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher uses a runtime called ART which natively supports loading multiple DEX files from APK files. ART performs pre-compilation at app install time which scans for classesN.dex files and compiles them into a single .oat file for execution by the Android device. Therefore if you have your min SDK set to 21 or higher, you do not need the multidex Library.

Here is a more detailed write up about the issue:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Answer (score 0):

**I successfully migrated the app to *androidx* using the below link and the second step:**

1) [Flutter Projects & Android X Migration Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54851489/flutter-projects-android-x-migration-issues)

2) In your android/app/build file increase the minsdkversion from 16 to 21 under defaultConfig. Some have even increased it to 28 but it worked for me at 21.

Comment: Regarding first step, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. That link can become invalid if the linked page changes, so that the answer would become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution without multidex or increasing min SDK. But it's need R8, just enable minify on App level build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
        release {
             minifyEnabled true
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
        }  
    }
```

from [github comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20747#issuecomment-614676669)
or to run debug without minify [github comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20747#issuecomment-615939017)

```
 buildTypes {
            release {
                 minifyEnabled true
            }
            debug {
                defaultConfig.minSdkVersion 21
            }  
        }
```