# Flutter app build failed after dependencies update

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

My Flutter project stopped working once I updated my dependencies. I am getting the following error:

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':firebase_core:compileDebugAidl'.

  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':firebase_core:debugCompileClasspath'.
  >   Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :firebase_core

Below is my `app\build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
}
```

Please see the below screenshot of error
[image]

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54857699/796963

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue, link mentioned by @Feu did not work for me. A bug has been opened https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30631

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue was fixed in the 0.3.4 update of firebase_core, which is a dependency of Flutter Firebase plugins. "flutter packages upgrade" may fix it for you.

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1464/files

Answer (score 2):

First, try this command:

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

if not works then run this:

```
flutter clean
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file(from flutter project) Flutter plugins/firebase_core-0.3.2/android/src/main/build.gradle was possibly missing the version for firebase, replace

```
 api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
```

with:

```
 api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
```

and it builds for me. I found it does not require the need for:

```
implemention 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
```

in flutter project android/app/build.gradle file.