# flutter build failed. Android dependency 'androidx.core:core' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.0.1) classpath

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am trying to build my flutter app but it gives this error:

> Android dependency 'androidx.core:core' has different version for the
>   compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.0.1) classpath. You should manually set
>   the same version via DependencyResolution

here is my android/build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    project.configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "28.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

try upgrading the gradle dependency: classpath from `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'` to `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'`

Comment: it is now returning this error: Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. I think I should use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54851489/flutter-projects-android-x-migration-issues what do you think?

Comment: this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54851489/flutter-projects-android-x-migration-issues solved my problem

Comment: For Flutter users, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27254#issuecomment-477474444 helped me

Answer (score 8):

Change versions in your project level `build.gradle` file

`kotlin_version` - **1.3.0**

`com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2` version - **3.3.2**

`com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2` version - **4.3.2**

Answer (score 1):

Change versions in your project level build.gradle file

Update `kotlin_version`, `com.android.tools.build:gradle:`, `com.google.gms:google-services:` to the latest versions.