# Problem with "multi_image_picker" in dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I have the problem with library **minSdk**: Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16, or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19
I Changed the build.gradle in the section **minSdkVersion** but show this:

D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

```
    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.prueba_2"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

```
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\52.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\54.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\56.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\57.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\58.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\59.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\60.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\61.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\62.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\63.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\64.jar, C:\Users\ANALYSIC-NABLA\Documents\Flutter\Development\prueba_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\65.jar
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.706], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.33.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

This plugin was migrated from using the deprecated Android Support Library to AndroidX. If your project was migrated to use it as well you should install version 4.X.X of the plugin. If you are using the old project structure please use version 2.4.11

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. 
tried to migrate to AndroidX using this method as suggested by flutter documentation :

1.tried menu Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX

2.got "No usages found"

I still had the error , so i tried the solution in this link (using the selected answer) :

[[Flutter Projects & Android X Migration Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54851489/flutter-projects-android-x-migration-issues][1])

And it worked perfectly