# Cannot Migrate Flutter Project to Android X which is using Firebase as Backend

Tags: firebase, flutter, androidx

I am trying  to migrate my flutter app to androidx but when i migrate it, it shows at popup saying

> No Usages Found in Project

This project is using firebase but before integrating  firebase it was working fine.

can anyone find solution for this problem?

Comment: If you had a picture, you somehow broke the link

Comment: Try the steps in this answer: [Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54851489/flutter-projects-android-x-migration-issues)