# How to migrate to AndroidX in my Flutter project?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, androidx

I tried to migrate my project. But I can't able to do it.

> **Migrate to AndroidX**
>
> > No Usages Found in the Project

Answer (score 2):

In gradle.properties add

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

In project build.gradle,

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.30'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Instead i had these and it works:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

or

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Comment: same result. No usage found in the project

Comment: May be this link can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54851489/flutter-projects-android-x-migration-issues

Answer (score 0):

Open the `android` folder of your `flutter` project in android studio. that should work.

if that does not work then you should do it manually.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate
Try this link, if you can understand it