# Adding Firestore dependency causes error in Flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

Adding `cloud_firestore: ^0.12.10` dependency in my flutter project gives errors.

These are the dependencies my project has:

```
dependencies:
  url_launcher: ^5.0.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.4

  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.10

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_messaging: ^5.1.6

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/launcher_icon/LauncherIcon.png"
```

I tried to use different cloud_firestore versions, but none of them worked.

This is the output of `flutter run` command in the terminal:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM A505F in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                              1.1s
Resolving dependencies...                                          16.3s
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[17.2.1,17.2.1]], but resolves to 16.5.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
> The library com.google.firebase:firebase-iid is being requested by various other libraries at [[20.0.0,20.0.0]], but resolves to 17.1.2. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        11.8s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

This is the output of `flutter doctor -v`:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.418], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.6 at D:\flutter_windows_v1.9.1+hotfix.2-stable\flutter
    • Framework revision 68587a0916 (8 weeks ago), 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0


[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\aditl\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 41.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] VS Code (version 1.40.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\aditl\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.6.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM A505F • RZ8M60LFVPP • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from you log errors

```
* What went wrong:
Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[17.2.1,17.2.1]], but resolves to 16.5.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
> The library com.google.firebase:firebase-iid is being requested by various other libraries at [[20.0.0,20.0.0]], but resolves to 17.1.2. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

you need to update firebase core to 17.2.1 if you have added it to your gradle files,

**Although this is an issue with your project not being androidX enabled**
[see how to migrate to androidX](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration)

**update**

```
    Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 81876 > 65536)
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
```

you need to enable [multidex](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) for your application
as follows

```
    android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: I followed the steps given on the page, but I got a `No usages found in the project` error. So, I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54857699/7608627) to manually migrate to AndroidX. I updated all the dependencies to their latest versions. Everything was working fine without the cloud_firestore dependency. When I added the `cloud_firestore: ^0.12.10` dependency, I got [this error](https://pastebin.com/3nU2eFgu).

Comment: @MasterAdit i updated my answer to fit multidex,also if you didnt add firestore correctly to your app consider checking this out https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup

Answer (score 2):

Add this line of code in your android/build.gradle file in the bottom. I think you missed the step of adding the services plugin.
Try this

and put  `cloud_firestore: ^0.12.10 dependency` below `firebase_messaging dependency`.

Code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I added `cloud_firestore: ^0.12.10` below `firebase_messaging`, but I am still getting an error.

I already have `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in `android/app/build.gradle` file (not in `android/build.gradle`). I also tried adding `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to `android/build.gradle`, but it gave me a different error.

Answer (score -1):

Add this line inside your target 'Runner' do block in your Podfile, e.g.:

```
# ...
target 'Runner' do
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.9.0'
# ...
end
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.