# Android dependency 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid' has different version for the compile (19.0.0) and runtime (20.0.1) classpath

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

An error occurs when trying to build an Android application with Flutter.

I've tried this solution but it doesn't work.

I want a hint to solve it.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid' has different version for the compile (19.0.0) and runtime (20.0.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
io.flutterio.flutterio.flutterandroidx.multidexcom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.android.supportio.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycleio.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestorecom.roughike.fluttertwitterlogin.fluttertwitterloginio.flutter.plugins.firebase.firebaseremoteconfigio.flutter.plugins.firebase_core_webio.flutter.plugins.firebaseauthio.flutter.plugins.imagepickerio.flutter.plugins.firebase.storageio.flutter.plugins.packageinfoio.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth_webio.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferencescom.flutter.keyboardvisibilityio.flutter.plugins.firebasemessagingio.flutter.plugins.url_launcher_macosio.flutter.plugins.firebase.coreio.flutter.url_launcher_webcom.tekartik.sqfliteio.flutter.plugins.urllauncherio.flutter.plugins.pathproviderandroidx.lifecycleandroidx.lifecycleandroidx.lifecycleandroidx.fragmentandroidx.annotationcom.google.firebaseandroidx.annotationandroidx.fragmentcom.google.android.gmscom.google.android.gmscom.google.android.gmscom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.guavacom.squareup.okhttpio.grpcio.grpcio.grpcio.grpcandroidx.collectionandroidx.localbroadcastmanagercom.google.android.gmscom.google.firebasecom.twitter.sdk.androidcom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.code.gsonandroidx.arch.corecom.google.android.gmscom.google.android.gmscom.google.android.gmsandroidx.coreandroidx.legacyandroidx.legacyandroidx.loaderandroidx.lifecyclecom.google.auto.valueandroidx.annotationcom.google.firebasecom.squareup.retrofit2com.squareup.retrofit2com.google.code.gsoncom.squareup.okhttp3com.google.android.gmscom.google.android.gmscom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.android.gmscom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.android.gmscom.google.android.gmscom.google.android.gmscom.google.android.gmscom.google.firebasecom.google.firebaseandroidx.lifecycleandroidx.versionedparcelableandroidx.customviewandroidx.viewpagerandroidx.coordinatorlayoutandroidx.drawerlayoutandroidx.slidingpanelayoutandroidx.interpolatorandroidx.swiperefreshlayoutandroidx.asynclayoutinflaterandroidx.cursoradapterandroidx.documentfileandroidx.printandroidx.lifecyclecom.google.auto.valuecom.google.protobufcom.squareup.okioio.grpccom.squareup.okhttpcom.squareup.okioio.grpccom.google.guavacom.squareup.okhttp3com.squareup.okiocom.google.firebasecom.google.android.gmscom.google.firebaseandroidx.lifecycleandroidx.arch.coreandroidx.arch.coreandroidx.lifecycleio.opencensusio.grpccom.google.androidio.opencensusio.grpccom.google.errorpronecom.google.code.findbugsorg.codehaus.mojoorg.checkerframeworkcom.google.j2objcio.flutterio.flutterio.flutterandroidx.multidexcom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.android.supportio.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycleio.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestorecom.roughike.fluttertwitterlogin.fluttertwitterloginio.flutter.plugins.firebase.firebaseremoteconfigio.flutter.plugins.firebase_core_webio.flutter.plugins.firebaseauthio.flutter.plugins.imagepickerio.flutter.plugins.firebase.storageio.flutter.plugins.packageinfoio.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth_webio.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferencescom.flutter.keyboardvisibilityio.flutter.plugins.firebasemessagingio.flutter.plugins.url_launcher_macosio.flutter.plugins.firebase.coreio.flutter.url_launcher_webcom.tekartik.sqfliteio.flutter.plugins.urllauncherio.flutter.plugins.pathproviderandroidx.lifecycleandroidx.lifecycleandroidx.lifecycleandroidx.fragmentandroidx.annotationcom.google.firebaseandroidx.annotationandroidx.fragmentcom.google.android.gmscom.google.android.gmscom.google.android.gmscom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.guavacom.squareup.okhttpio.grpcio.grpcio.grpcio.grpcandroidx.collectionandroidx.localbroadcastmanagercom.google.android.gmsandroidx.annotationcom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.twitter.sdk.androidcom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.code.gsonandroidx.corecom.google.firebasecom.google.firebaseandroidx.arch.corecom.google.android.gmscom.google.android.gmscom.google.android.gmsandroidx.coreandroidx.legacyandroidx.legacyandroidx.loaderandroidx.lifecyclecom.google.auto.valuecom.google.firebasecom.squareup.retrofit2com.squareup.retrofit2com.google.code.gsoncom.squareup.okhttp3com.google.android.gmscom.google.android.gmscom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.android.gmscom.google.firebaseandroidx.lifecycleandroidx.versionedparcelablecom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.firebasecom.google.android.gmscom.google.android.gmscom.google.android.gmscom.google.android.gmscom.google.firebaseandroidx.customviewandroidx.viewpagerandroidx.coordinatorlayoutandroidx.drawerlayoutandroidx.slidingpanelayoutandroidx.interpolatorandroidx.swiperefreshlayoutandroidx.asynclayoutinflaterandroidx.cursoradapterandroidx.documentfileandroidx.printandroidx.lifecyclecom.google.protobufcom.squareup.okioio.grpccom.squareup.okhttpcom.squareup.okioio.grpccom.google.guavacom.squareup.okhttp3com.squareup.okiocom.google.firebaseandroidx.lifecycleandroidx.arch.corecom.google.firebasecom.google.android.gmsandroidx.arch.coreandroidx.lifecycleio.opencensusio.grpccom.google.androidio.opencensusio.grpccom.google.errorpronecom.google.code.findbugsorg.codehaus.mojoorg.checkerframeworkcom.google.j2objccom.android.tools.build
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: Can you add your `build.gradle`?

Comment: Added to Answer.
please confirm

Answer (score 1):

`cloud_firestore` plugin is using new version of firestore which requires `androidX`. Therefore you need to migrate your application to `AndroidX`. You can find how to migrate here:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration#how-do-i-migrate-my-existing-app-plugin-or-host-editable-module-project-to-androidx

Comment: what couldnt u do, did you read this https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration#how-do-i-know-if-my-project-is-using-androidx?

Comment: Migrate to Android X
However, it results in No Usages Found in the Project.

Comment: @Fragons https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54851489/flutter-projects-android-x-migration-issues

Comment: I tried and got the following error:
```The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.0 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
root project 'android' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71
```

Comment: upgrade kotlin `ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'`

Comment: C:\Users\Nov\Documents\android\app\src\main\java\com\atgame\at_game\MainActivity.java:9: �G���[: �N���XApplication��public�ł���A�t�@�C��Application.java�Ő錾����K�v������܂�
public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
       ^
C:\Users\Nov\Documents\android\app\src\main\java\com\atgame\at_game\MainActivity.java:13: �G���[: FirebaseMessagingService�ɃA�N�Z�X�ł��܂���
    FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
                                   ^
  com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService�̃N���X�E�t�@�C����������܂�

Comment: Update flutter by doing flutter upgrade and create a new project

Comment: Did u try the above @Fragons

Answer (score 0):

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support' && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "version which should be used - in your case 11.6.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```