# Unable to use spread collections

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml

On using “...” error is shown that this requires the - -spread-collections experiment to be enabled.
Try enabling this experiment by adding it to the command line when compiling and running.  [error shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npmyd.png)
edit: i upgraded with the latest version of flutter but this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIN93.png) is shown

Even I tried adding enable-experiment: -spread-collections in pubspec.yaml file but didn't work

Comment: Which Dart version are you using? Seems like you need to upgrade.

Comment: Also, what sdk version is defined in your pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: yes i did an update with latest version but again new error is shown please help me out

Comment: I have attached the image of new error in the question

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment in your `pubspec.yaml` with

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: I did this but error is shown again that your app isn’t using Androidx

Comment: @DhanshreePajankar That's an altogether different error and should be a different question. Meanwhile have a look at this [this](https://medium.com/@carlosAmillan/fixing-androidx-error-in-flutter-f35e18d5925), [or this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54857699/6891637)

Comment: thanks it helped :) but now getting a different error